# My Thumbnails Caption not working right in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on making some thumbnails and using jquery to add some interactivity to them.

My caption only displays on the last thumbnail. It doesn't individually display the captions that I have set. How can I fix this so that it adds the captions when I hover on any of the thumbnails?

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ywgrkgs1/

Javascript:

```
$overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>');
$caption = $('<p class="caption"></p>')
$button= $('<button>More Info</button>');

$overlay.append($caption);
$overlay.append($button);

$(".thumbnail").append($overlay);
$(".overlay").hide();
$("#thumbnail-row li").mouseenter(function(event){
    var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
    $caption.text(captionText);

    $(this).children(".overlay").fadeIn(500);

}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tom's Thumbnails</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="thumbnail.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul id="thumbnail-row">
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
    <li class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02625/mountain1_2625884k.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed."/>
    </li>
    <p class="title">French Mountains</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02625/mountain1_2625884k.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum doletur adipiscing elit. Sed."/>
        </li>
        <p class="title">French Mountains</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail_container">
        <li class="thumbnail">
            <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02625/mountain1_2625884k.jpg" alt="onsectetur adipiscing elit. Sed."/>
        </li>
        <p class="title">French Mountains</p>
    </div>

</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="thumbnail.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code" is a requirement for a reason. If you want people to take the time to help you, take the time to ask your question properly.

Comment: that said, I did take a look at it, and it appears to be displaying all captions over the last image -- if you mouse over the third one, then mouse over to the second, you can see the second img's caption show up over the third before it fades out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript code you have the line:

```
$caption.text(captionText);
```

But after you appended `$caption` to `$overlay`, and `$overlay` to each `.thumbnail`, the `$caption` variable is going to be pointing at the last one that was added - that is, the caption on your third picture. So, every time you mouse over, that last caption element will have its text updated. You can see this if you quickly mouse over image 3 and then image 2 - image 2's alt text will show up over image 3 before it fades out.

Instead, to change the caption for *each* element, you need to use a selector, just like you did for fading each overlay:

```
$(this).children(".overlay").children(".caption").text(captionText);
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/f22j00Lf/1/

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH! whrrgarbl and next time i will ask question with the appropriate code. cheers

Comment: Glad that helped! Please consider accepting the answer if this fixed it for you :)